# Run email check after user stops typing

Tags: reactjs

I have a site that a user can make an account with their email. During signup, I want to run a function that waits until the user stops typing to run. This function will check to make sure that the value typed into the input is indeed an email, and if it is an email, it will send a quick API request to the backend server to check if that email address is already in use. I tried to utilize lodash's debounce method for this, but all I have managed to accomplish is making the function run for every character that is typed, and just debouncing the function each time. How can I achieve my desired effect?

Here is my function that runs onChange for my input:

```
const validateEmailChangeHandler = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setDataPayload({ ...dataPayload, [name]: value });

    debouncedEmailCheck(value);
  };
```

// debouncedEmailCheck

```
const debouncedEmailCheck = useCallback((str) => {
    const test = _.debounce(
      () => {
        if(validator.isEmail(str)) {
          console.log('input is email')
        } else {
          console.log('input is not an email')
        }
      },
      1000,
      false
    );

   

     test();

  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you attached the function to an on key press event, it is expected that it will run on every key press.

To mitigate the check on every key press, you have 2 (3) options.

1. Validate the email using regex, only when a valid email format is detected then make the call.
2. Check when the input has lost the user focus.
3. Some mechanism (as obfuscated hash or plain text) storing emails locally on page load, this will allow you to run the function as is with minimal changes - I wouldn't recommend this option though.

**Update:**

Take a look at this - it depends on your implementation and requirmenents:

- https://www.willmaster.com/library/tutorials/onkeydown-onkeyup-onclick-and-onchange-javascript-events.php
- [onkeyup vs onchange for number type input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237736/onkeyup-vs-onchange-for-number-type-input)
- https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php

Comment: I have it running onChange. Is a key press event better for this?