# How to not allow certain character to be entered when first player is playing the game?

Tags: javascript

```js
let firstplayerturn = 1;

if (firstplayerturn == 1) {
  value_input = document.getElementById("b1").value;
  if (value_input === "0") {
    alert("ERROR");
  }
  firstplayerturn = 0;
} else {

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="b1" class="box">
```

I was expecting that when first player is playing the game, "0" should not be taken as input.
That's why I try:

```
if (value_input === "0") {
    alert("ERROR");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have a function that executes your script when the input is entered.

```js
let firstplayerturn = 1;

function check(){
if (firstplayerturn == 1) {
  value_input = document.getElementById("b1").value;
  if (value_input === "0") {
    alert("ERROR");
  }
  firstplayerturn = 0;
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="b1" class="box">
<button onclick="check()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Instead of adding a button you could use the onclick event on the input tag itself.

Comment: That won’t work because input can’t be clicked

Comment: instead of onclick, you can use on of the following perhaps - onkeypress, onkeyup, onkeydown, onchange. I just found out, you can also use oninput: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237736/onkeyup-vs-onchange-for-number-type-input

Comment: Those will trigger it at the wrong time

Comment: I’ve just now tried them, but they constantly execute multiple times when I type a big number. I doubt OP wanted to only have one digit numbers, nor have their script executed multiple times. Thus my answer.